# scaling map/area with css, mobile web

Tags: html, mobile, css

Is it possible to scale map/area elements with pure css in at least, one mobile browser?
**no javascript!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, the answer might be yes, with css transforms:

```
img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(3, 3);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}
```

In Webkit desktop the map and areas get scaled along the image, I'd expect the same to be true of Webkit on mobile browsers.

Check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/q8hC2/

Comment: jsfiddle itself works very bad in mobile Safari (I have iPhone 3G to test), thus I can't test. Thanks for idea, though. I've tried -moz-scale in FF3.6 on map and area elements, but that didn't work. -moz-scale aplied to image works on areas too.

Comment: Perhaps the fullscreen version works better. http://jsfiddle.net/q8hC2/embedded/result/